# Need to return value from a function in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to return a value from a function but is not happening.

```
Public sub test()
  x = 2
  msgbox number(x)
Exit Sub

Public Function number(num)
  if len(num) = 1 then
     num = "0" + num
  End if
End Function
```

The function is returning a null value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the result to the name of the function, and concatenate the 0, like this:

```
Public Function number(num) As String
  if len(num) = 1 then
     number = "0" & num
  Else
     number = num
  End if
End Function
```

though it would seem easier to just use `Format(num, "00")`

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me
This was just an example for what i wanted to code as the original code has loads of confidential data.

Answer (score 3):

```
Public function number(num as string) as string
If len(num) = 1 then
    Number ="0" & num
Else 
    Number = num
End if
End function
```

You need to have code in the function that sets a value to the name of the function - the return value.